# How to get whole object using index

Tags: javascript, json

hi I have a json data i want to to get that object using index .? how can i do that ?
my json data is

```
[{
  "rec": ["act1","act2","act3"],
    "rec2": ["act11","act23","act4"]
}]
```

I need to get rec2 as I am passing index 1 . Please help

Comment: This is not possible as objects cannot be accessed by index. If you want to retrieve data by index or ordinal position, return your JSON as an array of objects, not an object that contains arrays.

Comment: If you use `json[0].rec2`, that will get rec2. The json you have is an array with a single item, so to access the single item use index 0. Then you have an object with two keys, rec1 and rec2, so you can access rec2 using that key.

Answer (score 1):

use `Object.keys`

```
var obj = [{
  "rec": ["act1","act2","act3"],
    "rec2": ["act11","act23","act4"]
}];


obj[0][Object.keys(obj[0])[1]]
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43sah2re/)

Answer (score 0):

You could tinker with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the corresponding named index:

```
var obj = [{
    "rec":  ["act1","act2","act3"],
    "rec2": ["act11","act23","act4"]
}];
var arr = obj[0][Object.keys(obj[0])[1]];
console.log(arr); // === ["act11", "act23", "act4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it in this way.

```
var json =[{
  "rec": ["act1","act2","act3"],
    "rec2": ["act11","act23","act4"]
}]
var index = 1;

var keys = Object.keys(json[0]);

console.log(json[0][keys[index]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest of ways, and not efficient for getting item where it's index is large!
you rather go with `Object.keys()` method described above,
included it here only to show another approach.

```
var a = eval("[{\"rec\": [\"act1\",\"act2\",\"act3\"], \"rec2\": [\"act11\",\"act23\",\"act4\"]}]");
var cnt = 2;
var second = null;
for(var itm in a[0])
{
    if(--cnt == 0){
        second = itm;
        break;
    }
}   
alert(second);
```